# Using a Meteor autoform-bs-datetimepicker for time only

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-autoform

There's a [Meteor wrapper](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform-bs-datetimepicker) for the [bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). In the bootstrap docs, you can specify selecting [time only](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-formats) (#datetimepicker3). I want to do this in Meteor. I've tried using

```
  {{> afQuickField name="departureTime" dateTimePickerOptions=timePickerOptions}}

  timePickerOptions : function() {
    return {
      format : 'LT'
    }
  },
```

however this still shows the calendar (although it does allow you to select the time). Is there something I'm  missing here?

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart same thing happens

Answer (score 2):

try to load it `with` your options, to be sure, that they are loaded before the template starts rendering..

```
{{#with timePickerOptions}}
  {{> afQuickField name="departureTime" dateTimePickerOptions=this}}
{{/with}}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without auto-form? I mean, maybe there is a problem with the library itself..

Comment: @ahota found the problem: autoform-bs-datetimepicker is not compatible with datetimepicker 4.x because of API change..